# How to make React.memo rerender logic deterministic in React functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization, rerender

I have a functional React component that uses `useState` and `useContext`, and it derives its display properties from both context and props.

I am using `useMemo` with its second argument, the `areEqual` function to *prevent the component from re-rendering when new props come in*.  There are dozens of values for the prop, but I only want to re-render the component when the prop changes to a specific value.

Here is a simplified example:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const {contextThing} = useContext();
  const {stateThing} = useState();
  const {propsThing} = props;

  // Since only foo changes what is rendered, I want to prevent rerendering unless the
  // prop changes to 'foo'
  const derivedThing = 
     (propsThing === 'foo' && contextThing === 'bar') ? 
     'foobar' : 
     null;

  return (
   <>
     <div>{contextThing}</div>
     <div>{stateThing}</div>
     <div>{propsThing}</div>
     <div>{derivedThing}</div>
   <>
}

function preventRerender(prevProps, nextProps) {
  if(prevProps.propsThing !== 'foo' }} nextProps.propsThing !== 'foo') {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

export default memo(MyComponent, preventRerender);
```

This successfully prevents the component from re-rendering, because one level up the tree, the `MyComponent` is wrapped with `MyComponentContainer`, which uses a custom hook
to drill the props into `MyComponent`, like so:

```
const MyComponentContainer = () {
  // Note: `useMyCustomHook` uses `useContext`, `useReducer` and `useState`
  const { propsThing } = useMyCustomHook();

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <MyComponent propsThing={propsThing} />
      <Footer />
    <>
  );
}

export default MyComponentContainer;
```

### The Problem

In reference to the `areEqual` function:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

React docs seem to say this is a bad practice.  I'm essentially treating `memo`/`areEqual` like a `shouldComponentUpdate` in a class component.

**I don't have control over when `propsThing` changes.  It is driven by both user actions and by pub/sub to a 3rd party API.**

Is this an anti-pattern that I need to replace with a different pattern?

Or is React just saying "*don't rely on this for features, because we may change how it works?*".

Is there are 3rd party solution to better handle this use case?

Comment: **Why** are you trying to prevent it from rerendering? EDIT: What you are doing definitely appears to be fighting against the framework, more information from you will probably lead to a simpler solution. In general, unless you see performance issues, you shouldn't be using `memo`. If you are seeing logical issues that are prevented with `memo`, then you've got a bug that should be fixed elsewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent re-rendering because I have incoming data, some of which needs to trigger a re-render.  It's not a bug, so much a question of architecture or technique.   Using memo for performance and user experience, yes.

Comment: We're in the process of devising another solution where another component/hook handles the incoming data, and only updates state/context that is relevant to the component using `memo`.  I'd still love an answer on "is this really a bad practice" or an alternate idea.   I'll post the new approach once it's implemented.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It's a bad practice, react tells you so (you quoted it). The reason why react tells you this is because react relies on memoization VERY heavily to remain fast. It reserves the right to, in the future, forget some memoized values depending on certain heuristics - meaning `useMemo` and `memo` will call their functions/components despite values not changing. I repeat, don't use memo if you don't see performance issues/jank. Memoizing stuff isn't free, don't assume it's always faster to use memo.

Comment: Thank for for the addtl color! We weren't seeing performance issues, but the "jank" was coming from too many re-renders. We've updated the architecture with a custom hook that parses incoming data, so now the component only gets the prop values that matter to it, rather than having to try to ignore incoming props. That update takes care of most of our use case, but we still want precise control over when a rerender is triggered.  Is that possible? it sounds like it is still a bad practice/not recommended. Is it fair to say: "If you need to control rerendering, something else is built wrong?"

Comment: For reference, `jank === performance issues`. Regarding: `Is it fair to say: "If you need to control rerendering, something else is built wrong?"` - 99% yes. Don't try to control rendering. Any immediate benefits will be more than offset by the inability to maintain the solutions in long term. For the record, the only time I every encounter this is in forms where I'm re-rendering on keystroke, and I've solved it in the past without memo's, instead using better state and/or component architecture.